# The Statute of Secrecy and Voldemort's regime

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

When the Death Eaters were managing the Ministry and rounding up Muggle-borns, were they also implementing their ideas of making the Muggles their slaves? And if yes, doesn't that mean that the Statute of Secrecy was annulled and the existence of wizards wasn't a secret any longer?

Comment: Statue of Secrecy was not annulled. If you are wondering that whether Voldemort complied with it or not, [See this question here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128306/would-voldemort-or-thicknesse-have-bothered-with-obliviating-muggles/128380)

Answer (score 7):

### Magic was still secret, but Voldemort was preparing to enslave Muggles

Voldemort had almost certainly not revealed the existence of magical individuals to Muggles at any point. We see a great deal of the Muggle world, albeit tangentially, in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, and at no point is there any sign of the sort of massive disruption or fighting that the reveal of Voldemort (and thus of witches and wizards generally) would have caused. Further, portions of *Deathly Hallows* that are set much later, along with other fiction written by Rowling, all support the idea that the wizarding population remained hidden:

> The commuters stared curiously at the owls as the family wove its way
> towards the barrier between platforms nine and ten.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

So I think we can safely say that Voldemort *did not* reveal himself to the world at large, and thus kept the existence of wizards a secret.

However, he probably had begun implementing his ideas of wizard dominance over Muggles. Even *before* he gained control of the Ministry, Voldemort was engaging in acts of violence against Muggles that were mostly pointless from the perspective of his war against the Ministry.

> “Since they have moved into the open, they have been wreaking havoc.
> The Brockdale Bridge — he did it, Prime Minister, he threatened a mass
> Muggle killing unless I stood aside for him and —”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

While this may have been advantageous insofar as it forced Ministry employees to work, in Fudge's words, "around the clock" to prevent a breach of the Statute of Secrecy, I suspect its main purpose was to indulge his and his followers' need to showcase their dominance over Muggles.

**Even more telling, Voldemort was attempting to gain control of the Muggle government before he took over the Ministry of Magic**:

> And was it his fault that one of his Junior Ministers, Herbert
> Chorley, had chosen this week to act so peculiarly that he was now
> going to be spending a lot more time with his family?
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

As we later see, someone attempted to put Chorley under the Imperius Curse:

> “Well, we’re not,” Scrimgeour cut in. **“It’ll be a poor lookout for the
> Muggles if their Prime Minister gets put under the Imperius Curse.** The
> new secretary in your outer office —”
>
> “I’m not getting rid of Kingsley Shacklebolt, if that’s what you’re
> suggesting!” said the Prime Minister hotly. “He’s highly efficient,
> gets through twice the work the rest of them —”
>
> “That’s because he’s a wizard,” said Scrimgeour, without a flicker of
> a smile. “A highly trained Auror, who has been assigned to you for
> your protection.”
>
> “Now, wait a moment!” declared the Prime Minister. “You can’t just put
> your people into my office, I decide who works for me —”
>
> “I thought
> you were happy with Shacklebolt?” said Scrimgeour coldly.
>
> “I am — that’s to say, I was —”
>
> “Then there’s no problem, is there?” said Scrimgeour. “I . . . well,
> as long as Shacklebolt’s work continues to be . . . er . . .
> excellent,” said the Prime Minister lamely, but Scrimgeour barely
> seemed to hear him.
>
> “Now, about Herbert Chorley, your Junior Minister,” he continued. “The
> one who has been entertaining the public by impersonating a duck.”
>
> “What about him?” asked the Prime Minister.
>
> **“He has clearly reacted to a poorly performed Imperius Curse,” said
> Scrimgeour. “It’s addled his brains, but he could still be dangerous.”**
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

That was a clear attempt to take control of the Muggle government. Further, this also shows that Scrimgeour found it quite plausible that Voldemort would seek to put the Muggle Prime Minister under the Imperius Curse.

**In other words, Voldemort was trying to take control of Muggle Britain even before he took over the Ministry—he most certainly would continued doing so thereafter.**

Voldemort had great contempt for Muggles, love, nonhumans, and indeed anyone who was not himself, but that did not prevent him from employing clever tactics. Just as he sought to take over the Ministry of Magic from within, so that he would control all wizards without them being the wiser, so too with Muggles. Perhaps he would eventually have revealed himself to both groups, but only when he could be sure of having no remaining credible opposition.

---

<sub>I doubt the Statute of Secrecy was specifically annulled. Recall that it is always referred to  as the *International* Statute of Secrecy, and thus could not be annulled by Britain alone (and recall that, as of *Deathly Hallows*, Voldemort only had control of magical Britain, not the entirety of the magical world).</sub>

> <sub>Upon the signature of the **International** Statute of Secrecy in 1689,
> wizards went into hiding for good.</sub>
>
> <sub>—*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## It’s unlikely - that could cause international wizard involvement.

The Dark Lord could kill Muggles and overthrow the British government of both wizards and Muggles without necessarily causing wizards in other countries to think it necessary to interfere. Muggle killings don’t seem to attract international attention unless there was also a violation of the Statute involved. It’s likely that the Dark Lord hadn’t started trying to actively break the Statute, even if the Ministry under his rule was less careful about keeping to it. If he showed blatant disregard for keeping the Statute of Secrecy, international wizards would likely step in - they still wouldn’t want the wizarding world revealed to Muggles. The Dark Lord was still trying to gain control of Britain, it’s unlikely he’d think it wise to do anything that would result in him trying to fight the international wizarding community as well while he barely had control of one nation and hadn’t defeated who he considered the biggest threat to his rule. The Statute of Secrecy is an internationally agreed upon wizarding law, and as such can be enforced by the International Confederation of Wizards, not just the Ministry of Magic.

> “The International Confederation of Wizards argued the matter out at their famous summit meeting of 1692. No fewer than seven weeks of sometimes acrimonious discussion between wizards of all nationalities were devoted to the troublesome question of magical creatures.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (textbook)*</sup></sub>

The International Confederation of Wizards is ultimately responsible for ensuring that all nations follow international wizarding laws. The Ministries of Magic ultimately have to answer to the International Confederation of Wizards, so if the Dark Lord was using the Ministry to take actions that violated the Statute, he’d likely have wizards from other countries trying to stop him. Controlling the Ministry was not enough to allow him to safely start enslaving Muggles.

> “In 1750, Clause 73 was inserted in the International Code of Wizarding Secrecy, to which wizard ministries worldwide conform today:
>
> Each wizarding governing body will be responsible for the concealment, care, and control of all magical beasts, beings, and spirits dwelling within its territory’s borders. Should any such creature cause harm to, or draw the notice of, the Muggle community, that nation’s wizarding governing body will be subject to discipline by the International Confederation of Wizards.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (textbook)*</sup></sub>

When nations break international wizarding law, the International Confederation of Wizards can punish the nation, and they can also send people to monitor the situation. They’d likely do something similar if the Dark Lord seemed to be a threat to the security of the wizarding world.

> “The International Confederation of Wizards has had to fine certain nations repeatedly for contravening Clause 73. Tibet and Scotland are two of the most persistent offenders. Muggle sightings of the yeti have been so numerous that the International Confederation of Wizards felt it necessary to station an International Task Force in the mountains on a permanent basis.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (textbook)*</sup></sub>

## It was an eventual goal - though likely one he was waiting to do.

The Dark Lord most likely did plan to enslave Muggles, and was probably working towards it. However, he was probably prioritizing things like corralling Mudbloods (since that only affected wizards it would likely be the sole jurisdiction of the Ministry of Magic) and leaving that until it was more practical. His next step, had he lived, may have been to Imperius the members of the International Confederation of Wizards, and repeal the Statute of Secrecy.

Answer (score 0):

Voldemort obviously didn't care whether or not the Muggles knew about wizards - he intended to make them his slaves. As far as I know, they had not reached the enslave-Muggles part of their plan yet.

Comment: It's much easier to create a statue showing you enslaving Muggles than it is to actually enslave them.